# Forcing QDialog to stay open

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qdialog

How should I best go about forcing a QDialog to stay open when the dialog's `accept()` slot is called? I was thinking of reimplementing that function to get the dialog's exec to return without hiding the dialog, but was wondering if there were any better ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than use a QDialog, I would accomplish the effect with a QDockWidget.

- Remove the feature that allows the dock to be moved (QDockWidget::DockWidgetMovable)
- Set the dock widget to floating (setFloating(true))
- Connect items on the dock widget to the appropriate signals and slots on the main window

**References**

- [Dock Widgets Example](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/mainwindows-dockwidgets.html)
- [QDockWidget Documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qdockwidget.html)

Comment: Hmm, but I am currently using `exec()` on that QDialog. How would I be able to get the main thread to wait while the user inputs some values in the `QDockWidget`?

Comment: Process the user data when the text changes on a child widget (or other sutable change). In other words connect the textChanged signal to your processing function.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately my code currently runs on a single thread that waits on the QDialog to finish `exec`. I supposed my best bet would be to refactor so that this isn't the case then?

Comment: Yeah it would involve moving the logic that handled the data from the dialog from after the exec call to its own method.  If you NEED to use a QDialog I can do some research for an answer to fit within the constraints.

Comment: Nah, it's good. I can do without a QDialog, thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your `QDialog` modeless, by calling `show` instead of `exec`, and using a custom signal instead of `accept`, because `accept` closes the window. And you connect that signal to a slot in the main window with the code you had after the `exec` call.

And in case that wasn't already the case, you should keep a reference/pointer to your QDialog somewhere (as a member in your main window class, or a static variable within the function that opens it) to be able to avoid creating multiple instances of the dialog, and you need to make sure you only connect the signals/slots once.